# How do I repeat the same question until user enters valid input without using the while loop?

Tags: python

I am writing a program that would help me compute average grade of a student.
I would like to enter a set of grades into the program, I will let the program know that I am done entering the grades by entering -1 as the grade. So until I enter -1, the program should keep asking me for another grade to enter. Once I am done entering grades, the program should output the average grade and sum of the grades.

```
grades = int(input("Enter grade: "))
if grades >= 1:
   grades = int(input("Enter grade: "))
elif grades == -1:
   exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you

```
Total = 0;
num = 0;

grades = int(input("Enter grade: "))

while grades != -1:
    if grades >= 1:
       Total = Total + grades #Calculate Total of grades
       num = num + 1; #Calculate number of grades

    grades = int(input("Enter grade: "))

avg = Total / num; #Calculate average

print(Total) #print Total
print(avg) #Print average
```

output -:

```
Enter grade: 2
Enter grade: 2
Enter grade: 3
Enter grade: -1
7
2.3333333333333335
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it would help if you made -1 a string keyword (or convert it to a string). It counts -1 as ANOTHER grade rather than an exit keyword. Hope this helps just a tad bit! :D

Comment: Can you share some code and explain why this would help please?